# Django 1.6 - Why can't I change from SQLite to PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, postgresql

I already changed the settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'examdatabase',
        'USER': 'examdatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': '11111',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I also installed PostgreSQL, and created a database:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
sudo apt-get install postgresql

sudo su - postgres 
createuser --superuser examdatabaseuser
psql
\password examdatabaseuser
createdb examdatabase
```

I deleted the sqlite database file in my project, but when I run the command `python manage.py runserver` it still uses sqlite. Why?

Related info: I use virtualenv (/home/py3env). Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

Comment: The config is correct. Check that the variable is not getting redefined anywhere later and there is no another settings module in a directory from `sys.path` before your project dir.

Comment: @Igonato I added a print('ahahah') in settings.py and when runserver or uwsgi, it does print.

Comment: @xiang did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180181/how-do-i-switch-from-sqlite-to-postgres-in-django